# Dataframe convert categories to numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with many variables. The variables that they are categories, I want to transform them into numbers values.

For instance, I have these values in the variable of the dataframe:

```
ID | VarEx
0 | key
1 | door
2 | key
3 | key
4 | chair
5 | chair
6 | tv
7 | door
8 | tv
```

I want to replace into a numbers values with a loop because in others variables I have about 1000 distinct values. This is the exit that I expect:

```
ID | VarEx
0 | 0
1 | 1
2 | 0
3 | 0
4 | 2
5 | 2
6 | 3
7 | 1
8 | 3
```

How can I do that with a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
df['VarEx'] = pd.Categorical(df['VarEx']).codes
```

Output:

```
   ID  VarEx
0   0      2
1   1      1
2   2      2
3   3      2
4   4      0
5   5      0
6   6      3
7   7      1
8   8      3
```

Comment: That's a nice approach @PaulS with `Categorical`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using [`pd.factorize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html)

```py
cols = df.select_dtypes(include=["object"]).columns
for col in cols:
    df[col] = pd.factorize(df[col])[0]
    
print(df)
```

---

```
   ID  VarEx
0   0      0
1   1      1
2   2      0
3   3      0
4   4      2
5   5      2
6   6      3
7   7      1
8   8      3
```